# Android intent chooser does not display list if earlier intent is not finished

Tags: android, android-intent

With the code below I share some text from my app via an intent chooser. My problem is that if I for example choose to share the text as a message and when in the message app I just hit the home button and bring my app back to front. Then when I try to start a new intent chooser it immediately sends me back to the unfinished message app. I would rather that it forgot all about that and presented me with the list of choices again.

Is there a way to make it forget the old choice?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share text as..."));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);